# Discontinuity of the indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, special-functions

Consider the function $q(x,\theta)=1\{ x \in \{x \text{ s.t. } \theta+x_i>0 \text{ }\forall i \}\}$ where 1 is the indicator function taking value 1 if the condition inside $\{ \}$ is satisfied and zero otherwise, $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $x_i$ is the ith component of the vector $x$ and $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R^k}$. Is this function not continuous both in $x$ and $\theta$? How can I show it?

Comment: What is $S(\theta)$?

Comment: The answer all depends on $S$, obviously.

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you!

Comment: You know, it's not necessary to say $x\in\{x\text{ s.t. }\phi\}$; this is the same as just $\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u$ denote the vector of ones, then, for every real number $t$ and every vector $x$, one has $q(x+tu,-x)=\mathbf 1_{t\gt0}$ and $q(x,-x+tu)=\mathbf 1_{t\lt0}$. What does this tell you?